# sharepoint wspbuilder single aspx page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wspbuilder

Im trying to implement a single aspx page with several externals dll's. Following Zimmergren's tutorial I run into a couple of issues early in the process. After creating my blankfeature1 is it suppose to be automatically populated? Mine shows empty.

Im also scoping the assembly to the bin, after I configure that and build the wsp I dont get a wsp file afterwards? Which according to the tutorial I should. Any ideas?

Tutorial Link: http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below blog may helps you

http://www.allaboutmoss.com/index.php/2010/03/05/how-to-create-wsp-package-for-user-controls/